# How to passing array values from ajax to spring xml controller

Tags: ajax, spring

I am creating  survey page which has the following ajax to pass answer values

```
if(check==0)
        {
            var surveyVal="";

            var len=answers.length;
            for(i=0;i<=len-1;i++)
            {
                if(i!=len-1)
                surveyVal+="val"+i+"="+answers[i]+"&";
                else
                surveyVal+="val"+i+"="+answers[i];
            }
            var ajaxUrl = "survey.do";
            var data = surveyVal;
            alert(data);


            var returnValue = false;
            tinymce.util.XHR.send({


                   url : ajaxUrl,
                   content_type : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                   type : "POST",
                   data : {values: data.toString() },


                   success : function(data) {
                    alert("Done! Content Saved")




                     // Do anything you need to do if save successful
                     ed.setProgressState(false); // cancel showing progress    
                   },      

                   error : function( type, req, o ){     
                    alert("Save Failed\n Error: " + type + "\n HTTP Status: " + req.status);        
              }                 

                     });
```

//the alert gives

> val0=0,val1=2

etc as per the options I have chosen at the browser . how can I take these val to my controller as it is so that I can capture in logs and  save in my database as individual answers . (please note I cant use annotation)

currently controller is like this which is not working

```
 String val0 = request.getParameter("val0");
            String val1 = request.getParameter("val1");
            String val2 = request.getParameter("val2");
            String val3 = request.getParameter("val3");
            String val4 = request.getParameter("val4");



        logger.info                 + "|"+ToolsUser.getPlatform() 
                        + ">Update Survey Inputs"
                        + "|Answers:"
                        + "|Answer-1:"+val0
                        + "|Answer-2:"+val1
                        + "|Answer-3:"+val2
                        + "|Answer-4:"+val3
                        + "|Answer-5:"+val4

                        );
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

can you replace this line

```
data : {values: data.toString() },
```

with this

```
data : "values=" data.toString(),
```

and in your controller try to get the value of

```
request.getParameter("values");
```

and let me know if this worked for you

Comment: sorry but what do u mean by try to get the value of request.getParameter("values");you mean val0,val1 etc??

Comment: no, i mean what is the value of request.getParameter("values"); when you debug in controller?

Comment: Sorry ,its not working , still not reaching my controller |Answer-1:null|Answer-2:null|Answer-3:null|Answer-4:null|Answer-5:null|

Comment: Hi, in the code in the controller can you also add String values = request.getParameter("values"); and print this value?

Comment: hey I made some changes, it worked . thanks a lot. a

Comment: Nice to hear that, what changes have you made?